# Merge multiple block views to a single jump menu

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I want to implement a jump menu with a list of three different vocabulary terms grouped by each vocabulary name. If I make only a single view all the terms are shown correctly but I would like to be grouped by their vocabulary names. I thought that I could have this result if I could merge three different views with a view for each vocabulary.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Well... It was very simple. I just used a single block view with all the vocabularies and I just used "Group by" the field vocabulary name. This outputs the option values within optgroups for each vocabulary.